# What is the proper way to change Firebase data structure?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a Firebase database in working.

Suddenly I want to add an additional field in an object. What's the proper way to do it?

1. Export the data json file then add it manually?
2. Add it programmatically?

What's your suggestions for modifying the Firebase schema?

Cheers
Well

Comment: I would do it programmatically in Go/Python and libraries for Firebase REST API, if objects that need to be modified is more than 100

Comment: But question is really very subject based, it doesn't has answer, you better delete it before you get downvotees

Comment: There is no single best way to modify your data structure. It all depends on the change you're looking to make and the how resilient your existing clients are to changes. Without considering a very specific case (data+code), this is too broad a topic to answer.