# How to modify the database structure in firebase using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I already have a database structure like this `users/$uid/notes` what's the recommended way to alter the existing database records to create a new structure? For example `users/$email/notes`.

In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734586/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-firebase-data-structure) they recommended exporting the db to JSON, modifying it and importing it. I would prefer to do this programmatically (directly on the database).

I think my biggest problem with this question is that I'm missing some conceptual leap: since I have a JS+firebase app using the web client SDK, how do I write a one-off script that does something simple like list the existing users? Do I need to open the node REPL and run it there?